# Rename xticks in seaborn boxplot

Tags: python, seaborn

Is there a default function/method in seaborn to rename the xticks of a boxplot without the need of changing the input data frame?

I haven't seen anything in [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) neither googling this

Comment: Did you check my answer? Is there anything missing?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is not what I wanted. See the answer I have added.

Comment: I saw your answer and did not understand what the difference was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This replace the name of the box

```
ax.set_xticklabels(["First box","Second box"])
```

Comment: It is interesting how I got three -3 in the question although this question has more than 2.5K views

Answer (score 6):

Since there is no code or data, customizing the x-axis label based on the example from the official reference can be done by setting any string. As an addition, ticks can also be achieved by converting an existing string or setting a list with the same number of ticks.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
xlabel = ax.get_xlabel()
print(xlabel)
labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
print(labels)
labels = [x.get_text().upper()for x in labels]
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.set_xlabel('dayofweek')
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Graph before customization**
[image]